# Android FATAL EXCEPTION: main Could not init DAOConfig

Tags: android, proguard

My project is in kotlin and java, it works find when setup `minifyEnabled false` but when setup `true` I got the error:

```
2021-11-03 17:21:33.770 9089-9089/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
yb.d: Could not init DAOConfig
        at bc.a.<init>(:94)
        at yb.b.a(:44)
        at x2.d.<init>(:56)
        at b3.h.<init>(:62)
        at b3.i.d(:39)
        at b3.i.b(:30)
        at b3.i.c(:9)
        at t8.a.c(:47)
        at b3.d0.b(:58)
        at b3.d0.c(:14)
        at n5.n.b(:31)
        at n5.n.c(:10)
at com.xxx.xxx.login.LoginFragment.B0(:71)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.e1(:2963)
        at androidx.fragment.app.t.f(:518)
        at androidx.fragment.app.t.m(:282)
        at androidx.fragment.app.m.d0(:2189)
        at androidx.fragment.app.m.e1(:2106)
        at androidx.fragment.app.m.a0(:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.m$g.run(:524)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: TABLENAME
at java.lang.Class.getField

2021-11-03 17:21:33.797 1693-2221/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '8bcfc29 com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.activity.AppActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

I googled the solutions, basically change the `proguard-rules.pro`
Right now:

```
-keep class org.greenrobot.greendao.**{*;}
-keepclassmembers class * extends org.greenrobot.greendao.AbstractDao {
public static java.lang.String TABLENAME;
}
-keep class **$Properties { *; }
-keep class com.xxx.domain.model.**{ *; }
-keep class com.xxx.data.dao.**{ *; }
# If you DO use SQLCipher:
-keep class org.greenrobot.greendao.database.SqlCipherEncryptedHelper { *; }
-keepclassmembers class **$Properties {
    public static <fields>;
}
# If you do NOT use SQLCipher:
-dontwarn net.sqlcipher.database.**
# If you do NOT use RxJava:
-dontwarn rx.**
```

And here is my GreeDao version:

```
implementation 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.3.0'
```

project level:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.3.0'
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5")
    }
```

I'm not quite sure what went wrong, the main changes before it works is mainly adding navigation components.
Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**:
Added this for ignore the Serializable, but still no luck.

```
-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of stupid,

```
debug {
     minifyEnabled false
     xxx
}
```

After turning on `false`, this line still under `release {}` block:

`proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'`
Anyway hope this help others too.